# How to secure HTTPS on Django using Pythonanywhere?

Tags: django, ssl, https, pythonanywhere

I'd like to be able to have a securee site (https) with the green padlock. I followed this tutorial from pythonanywhere's help center a month ago, https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/LetsEncrypt/ and I set up everything correctly :

```
git clone https://github.com/lukas2511/dehydrated.git ~/dehydrated
mkdir -p ~/letsencrypt/wellknown
cd ~/letsencrypt
WELLKNOWN=/home/YOURUSERNAME/letsencrypt/wellknown
~/dehydrated/dehydrated --cron --domain www.yourdomain.com --out . --challenge http-01
```

The problem is that when I enter my site using https I get a message and cannot access my site since Google warns me of the risk of the site. I tried to use www.whynopadlock.com to find what was wrong and here is what it gives :

> SSL verification issue (Possibly mis-matched URL or bad intermediate cert.). Details:
>   ERROR: no certificate subject alternative name matches SSL verification issue (Possibly mis-matched URL or bad intermediate cert.). Details:
>   ERROR: no certificate subject alternative name matches.

Have anyone set up an HTTPS using Pythonanywhere ? What are the steps to set up correctly so the green padlock is there.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you missed out the last step on the instructions: "To get your certificate installed email support@pythonanywhere.com to let us know that you want us to install your certificate. Include your username, the directory path to the certificates, and the domain name and we'll do the rest."

Comment: I did not miss this step. I did send them everything a while now and nothing happened I think the error was coming on my side since I have trust in pythonanyhwere's team.

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- we normally respond to any emails within an hour or two during UK business hours, and always within 24 hours.  It's possible your one got lost somewhere in the ether -- could you try sending us a message again?